# cucumber/ruby: possible to output the "puts" to a --format html file?

Tags: html, ruby, cucumber, string-formatting

I've got some ruby tests that are calling different modules, classes where they detail what they're doing with some "puts" commands during execution.

If you run those tests in the console then you will see the output of the "puts" command in the console but if you run the tests with the option:

```
ruby --format html --output file.html
```

then all that information is lost. Is there a way to log simple string messages inside the HTML report?

Comment: Are the "puts" command outputs part of the expected output from your program? Or are they for debugging/informational purpose? If they are expected output from your program, they are best captured in the HTML report by writing features that expect these lines. See this [blogpost](http://blog.jcoglan.com/2009/11/14/testing-command-line-apps-with-cucumber/) for examples. If the "puts" output are for debugging, then you shouldn't be trying to put them into the HTML report; it's not a recommended practice.

Comment: Those outputs are really failures captured in the rescue of a specific module so I don't think that we can write specific feature for those errors, ie, the feature is already there, we loop through around 100 URLs, some of them fail and we want to output that failure in the HTML report. Do you know a way to capture those failures in the HTML report?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following steps:

```
When /^I do something$/ do
  puts "Hello"
end

Then /^something happens$/ do
end
```

...with the following command:

```
cucumber -f html -o results.htm
```

...when I opened up the `results.html` file in a browser, it displayed the "Hello" message just after displaying the step. I've attached the pertinent section of the HTML output so you can see that the output from `puts` is there:

```
<!-- the first step -->
<li id='features_thing_feature_4' class='step passed'>
    <div class="step_name">
        <span class="keyword">When </span>
        <span class="step val">I do something</span>
    </div>
    <div class="step_file">
        <span>features/step_definitions/thing_steps.rb:1</span>
    </div>
</li>
<!-- anything that the above step passed to `puts` -->
<li class="step message">Hello</li>
<!-- the second step -->
<li id='features_thing_feature_5' class='step passed'>
    <div class="step_name">
        <span class="keyword">Then </span>
        <span class="step val">something happens</span>
    </div>
    <div class="step_file">
        <span>features/step_definitions/thing_steps.rb:5</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

What that demonstrates is that when cucumber's `puts` method is called (ie: directly from within a step) the output will be included in the html output. But if the `puts` call is from somewhere else (eg: your modules) then it won't be included. You could consider moving your `puts` calls from the modules to the steps. Also,  using `puts` isn't really best practice so you may want to consider removing it altogether...

Comment: Ah, I think that might be the problem... as the puts are written within specific modules.

If that way to output information is not the best way, what's a better approach to display where something's failing? Right now we've got a module that's called like 100 times to check different URLs; if the call fails it's just captured via a rescue and we manually output the message via a 'put' so that the script doesn't stop. But in practice, it's a failure that would be useful to see as such on the HTML report...

Any idea about how to achieve that?

Comment: The best way would be to expose the result to the test and assert it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can remember World in Before hook of each scenario:

```
# features/support/env.rb
Before do |scenario|
  $world = self
end
```

Then in your support classes and modules outside world you can use puts as:

```
$world.puts 'something'
```

Also you can get/set Cucumber instance variables as:

```
$world.instance_variable_get(:@user)
$world.instance_variable_set(:@user, user)
```

I also prefer to extract those 2 methods to helpers for better visibility:

```
module Helpers
  def get_scenario_variable(symbol)
    $world.instance_variable_get(symbol)
  end

  def set_scenario_variable(symbol, value)
    $world.instance_variable_set(symbol, value)
  end
end
```

Then you can include this module where you need those methods