# Cucumber colored output changes depending on where I print text

Tags: ruby, cucumber

When I print output straight from the Given/When/Then statements of cucumber, it prints in a nice blue text, however if I call into any other function and print within there, it prints in red (and not indented)

Sample feature:

```
Feature: Foo
  Scenario: Foo2
    Given something
    Then something else
```

Sample step_def:

```
Given /^something$/ do
  puts "Pretty blue"
end

class AnyClass
  def doSomething
    puts "Scary red"
  end
end

Then /^something else$/ do
  AnyClass.new.doSomething
end
```

In the below sample output, "Scary red" is red, not indented at all, and actually printed before the cucumber step (The "Then" clause).  "Pretty blue" is blue, indented appropriately, and outputted after the cucumber step.

```
Feature: Foo

  Scenario: Foo2
    Given something
      Pretty blue
Scary red
    Then something else

1 scenario (1 passed)
2 steps (2 passed)
0m0.001s
```

I am new to Ruby & cucumber so I am not even positive those are the appropriate tags for this question.  Is there a way to make output from methods called within other classes will match the pretty formatting?

Edit: Some more searching has shown that puts from within steps are handled differently (as in, if you format it differently, they are included) than puts from other functions (which get excluded from other formatters).  So perhaps the question is, how does Ruby intercept the puts from the steps?  I suspect they're implementing their own puts which is part of the step's class then.

Comment: Looks related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745662/cucumber-ruby-possible-to-output-the-puts-to-a-format-html-file/12944936

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing the grammar for cucumber steps, cucumber has overridden (the grammars) puts to be colored and buffered.  The color depends on whether the step passes or not, and the buffering happens because it won't color the output until everything has run (so it knows which color to print).

Passing self from within a grammar step and calling that objects puts gets the behavior I was after.

The red was a side effect of my default font color.

ie:

```
After /Some Condition/ do
   some_object.test_something(self)
end

class SomeObject
   def test_something(obj)
      obj.puts "SomeText"
   end
end
```