# How to print/embed logs into report.html in calabash android

Tags: cucumber, calabash-android

How can I print/assert/embed logs into a report.html file generated?
e.g

```
Then(/^I do some crazy stuff$/) do
  puts "this scenario does crazy stuff"
end
```

**this scenario does crazy stuff** should appear in the report.html.
If I use **puts** it print output on a terminal which is not desired by me.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help but I found a similar question with an answer. [cucumber/ruby: possible to output the "puts" to a --format html file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745662/cucumber-ruby-possible-to-output-the-puts-to-a-format-html-file)